# How to create Editable gridpanel

Tags: extjs

I have created a grid. I just want to know how to make it editable.Though I can find many examples over here.I am not being able to understand it as I am new to it. Can you please tell me in simple way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cell` or `rowedit` functions in grid. The following examples show how you can do.

[Cell Edit Sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/49t)

```
// Cell Edit example
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        /**
         * here is the important part
         * you should define each or single column 'editor' property
         * then specify the 'plugins' that you want to use, here is 'CellEditing'
         * as you might guess, all definitions appear in the grid definition
         */             
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
    ],
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

[Row Edit Sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/49u)

```
// Row Edit Sample
// the difference with cell edit, just showing an editor screen to change something
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224"},
        {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1234"},
        {"name":"Homer", "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244"},
        {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"}
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        /**
         * Same aspect
         * you should define 'editor' property
         * if you don't define editor property for a colum, 
         * you can't change anyhthing for that column
         */
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
        // here is the plugin definition
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```